# Samsung Galaxy S4, Model #: SGH-I337M Always disconnects when using Odin

Tags: android, root

I tried to root my android phone, but it disconnected while I was rooting, and now it is soft-bricked. I tried to hard-reset it, but it just keeps taking me back to the screen that says "Firmware upgrade encountered an issue. Please select recovery mode in Kies and try again." I tired to recover using Kies, but Kies would not recognize my phone. So, I downloaded my firmware and I am trying to install it using Odin. However, this is the output I get:

```
<ID:0/003> Added!!
<OSM> Enter CS for MD5..
<OSM> Check MD5.. Do not unplug the cable..
<OSM> Please wait..
<OSM> I337MVLUAMDJ_I337MOYAAMDJ_I337MVLUAMDJ_HOME.tar.md5 is valid.
<OSM> Checking MD5 finished Sucessfully..
<OSM> Leave CS..
<ID:0/003> Odin v.3 engine (ID:3)..
<ID:0/003> File analysis..
<ID:0/003> SetupConnection..
<ID:0/003> Initialzation..
<ID:0/003> Removed!!
<ID:0/003> Get PIT for mapping..
<ID:0/003> There is no PIT partition.
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)
<ID:0/003> Removed!!`
```

The device always seems to disconnect when it tries to install the firmware. I have tried using different usb ports, as well as different computers. I am wondering if I need to use another usb cable, however, note that I just bought this cable a couple months ago from amazon, and so it should be fine. Are there any solutions to this problem?

Also, if anyone knows the correct version of Odin that one should use for installing firmware on Samsung S4, model SGH-I337M, that would also be a great help. I am currently using Odin V 1.85.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was the USB cable, tried a different cable, not even the original one from samsung, just a random one and it worked.